# Factoring Polynomials (x^4) - using completing squares

Tags: polynomials, factoring, completing-the-square

[image]

> **Exercise 6.** By viewing the polynomials as a difference of two squares, factorise the following polymomials.
>
> 1. $x^4+x^2+1$,
> 2. $x^4+3x^2+4$,
> 3. $x^4+4$.

To solve difference of two squares isnt it necessary to have negatives? im confused about how to start solving these questions. I cant seem to factorise by grouping either /:

Information on how to factorise these types of questions would be appreciated. thank You!

Comment: For the first, note that $x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+1)^2-x^2$. Similar ideas will handle the other two.

Comment: Completing the square for a monic quadratic polynomial (leading coefficient $=1$, degree $=2$) yields an expression of the form $(x-h)^2+k$, which is a difference of squares (if the potentially complex numbers $\sqrt{-k}$ are allowed to be considered). Of course quartic functions (degree $=4$) with no $x^3$ or $x$ terms can be considered as quadratics in the variable $x^2$.

Comment: Just try completing a square by adding (and subtracting) another square. For e.g. $x^4+4=(x^4+4x^2+4)-4x^2$. Now you can factorise in integer polynomials.

Comment: @Hans I don't think this is a duplicate. There is room here for an answer on a broader level that addresses more general approaches to such factorisation problems.

Answer (score 3):

1. $x^4+x^2+1= (x^2)^2+(x^2)\cdot 1+1^2=(x^2)^2+2\cdot (x^2)\cdot 1+1^2- (x^2)\cdot 1=(x^2+1)^2-x^2=(x^2+1-x)(x^2+1+x)=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1).$
2. $x^4+3x^2+4= (x^2)^2+3\cdot (x^2)+2^2=(x^2)^2+4\cdot (x^2)+2^2-x^2=(x^2)^2+2\cdot 2\cdot x^2+2^2-x^2=(x^2+2)^2-x^2=(x^2+2-x)(x^2+2+x)=(x^2+x+2)(x^2-x+2).$
3. $x^4+4=(x^2)^2+2^2 =(x^2)^2+2\cdot 2\cdot x^2+2^2-4x^2=(x^2+2)^2-(2x)^2=(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2).$

The idea is that if you have something like: $a^2+b^2+kab$ you can add and subtract something which in your case gives you a square (the exercise is of such a nature). $a^2+b^2+2ab+(k-2)ab=a^2+b^2+2ab-(2-k)ab=(a+b)^2-(2-k)ab$.
In your examples:

1. $a=x^2, b=1, k=1$
2. $a=x^2, b=2, k=1$
3. $a=x^2, b=2, k=0$.